# How to sterilize infant feeding bottles while traveling?

Tags: air-travel, airports, children

Does anyone know how one could go about sterilizing infant feed bottles (and teets) while traveling ?

At the moment, the plan is to travel with microwaveable bags (where in I can put the bottles and microwave them). I have transit in Singapore and am trying to find how/where I can access a microwave in the airport ?

Of course, I am not the first one to be facing this problem. So, trying to find how people take care of infant feeding bottles while on the go ?

Comment: Maybe chemical sterilisation could be an option?

Comment: Maybe not worry about it so much and use bottled purified water for washing them - http://www.webmd.com/parenting/baby/should-you-sterilize-your-babys-bottles

Comment: Will boiling water do the trick? You could try asking for some at bars and cafes.

Comment: I think your best bet for finding a microwave is one of the [convenience stores](http://www.changiairport.com/en/airport-experience/attractions-and-services/convenience-stores.html). If hot water is enough, then you could use one of the [baby care rooms](http://www.changiairport.com/en/airport-experience/attractions-and-services/baby-care-room.html), which according to their website should have hot water dispensers. Tap water is generally very safe in Singapore, so I don't think you will even need purified water to wash them.

Answer (score 2):

To sterilise the bottles, you can grab a pack of cold water sterilising tablets, which work well to sterilise the bottle.

Alternatively, you can try sterilising the bottles and teats by boiling it water.

If those options are not available, you can always get presterilised disposable bottles.